# How to add an average column in a group by rollup() query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to show an average in a fairly simple query, but I am not sure how I can get one in this context. The requirement is to display how many samples are obtained in a medical procedure (by physician and then by procedure).

I currently have a query that will get me this result:

```
+----------------------+-------------+------------+------------------+
|       Physician      |  Procedure  | Total Jars | Total Encounters |
+----------------------+-------------+------------+------------------+
| NULL                 | NULL        |        531 |              790 |
| Smith MD, Benjamin A | NULL        |        531 |              790 |
| Smith MD, Benjamin A | Procedure A |        379 |              581 |
| Smith MD, Benjamin A | Procedure B |        128 |              180 |
| Smith MD, Benjamin A | Procedure C |         24 |               29 |
+----------------------+-------------+------------+------------------+
```

There will of course be more physicians in the list, so the rollup will be more helpful then. What is also desired is the average number of jars obtained (again by physician and procedure).

I will include my query here, but I feel like I'd better give a little more background, just in case it is pertinent to any potential recommendations.

The 'Total Jars' data is stored in 12 tables, which all contain the same fields and should have, from the beginning, been a single table. I know it's bad design, but it's what I have to work with right now.

For each encounter, there may be 0 to 12 samples obtained, so in order to bring in the data, I am doing a left join on a CTE, which is really just a big UNION of any records that belong in the search criteria. Because I don't have the total number of samples obtained inside a single table record (for each encounter), I can't do a simple AVG.

I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to best get the average worked into the query. Here is my current query:

```
DECLARE  @start_date VARCHAR(8)
        ,@end_date VARCHAR(8)
        ,@practice_id CHAR(4)

SET      @start_date = '20130601'
SET      @end_date = '20140601'
SET      @practice_id = '0001'

;WITH jars
AS
(
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle_1_ b1 ON pe.enc_id = b1.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b1.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle2_ b2 ON pe.enc_id = b2.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b2.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle3_ b3 ON pe.enc_id = b3.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b3.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle4_ b4 ON pe.enc_id = b4.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b4.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle5_ b5 ON pe.enc_id = b5.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b5.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle6_ b6 ON pe.enc_id = b6.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b6.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle7_ b7 ON pe.enc_id = b7.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b7.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle8_ b8 ON pe.enc_id = b8.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b8.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle9_ b9 ON pe.enc_id = b9.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b9.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle10_ b10 ON pe.enc_id = b10.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b10.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle11_ b11 ON pe.enc_id = b11.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b11.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle12_ b12 ON pe.enc_id = b12.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b12.eso1, '') <> ''
)

SELECT              pm.description AS [Physician],
                    e.event AS [Procedure],
                    COUNT(j.enc_id) AS [Total Jars],
                    COUNT(pe.enc_id) AS [Total Encounters]
FROM                patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN          person p ON pe.person_id = p.person_id AND pe.practice_id = @practice_id
INNER JOIN          appointments ap ON pe.enc_id = ap.enc_id
                                    AND ap.resched_ind = 'N'
                                    AND ap.delete_ind = 'N'
                                    AND ap.cancel_ind = 'N'
                                    AND ap.appt_kept_ind = 'Y'
INNER JOIN          events e ON ap.event_id = e.event_id
INNER JOIN          provider_mstr pm ON pe.rendering_provider_id = pm.provider_id
INNER JOIN          location_mstr lm ON pe.location_id = lm.location_id
LEFT JOIN           (SELECT enc_id
                     FROM jars
                     GROUP BY enc_id) AS j ON pe.enc_id = j.enc_id
WHERE               pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
    ( (pm.description, e.event)
      ,ROLLUP(pm.description)
    )
ORDER BY pm.description, e.event
```

Also, I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: It is not really clear what information you want to display. Can you show us the desired output based on the sample provided

Comment: Sorry, it is still not clear. Are you happy with the bottom three rows? Do you now want to get an average figure of these three rows and display it in the top two rows?

Comment: Yes, I'm happy with the bottom three rows. I just need to be able to calculate the average number of samples (jars) taken per procedure. I was thinking of doing it as another column, but I couldn't get that to work correctly.

Comment: So, for example, I'd like the average number of samples taken by Dr. Smith for each procedure, then for all of his procedures combined, as well as being able to calculate the overall average for all physicians.

Comment: This gives mostly 0's and some 1's in the average column. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: If you meant my updated answer, then check it up again. I have casted it to FLOAT. Now, the calculation should be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with ROLLUP:

```
;WITH jars
AS
(
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle_1_ b1 ON pe.enc_id = b1.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b1.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle2_ b2 ON pe.enc_id = b2.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b2.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle3_ b3 ON pe.enc_id = b3.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b3.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle4_ b4 ON pe.enc_id = b4.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b4.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle5_ b5 ON pe.enc_id = b5.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b5.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle6_ b6 ON pe.enc_id = b6.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b6.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle7_ b7 ON pe.enc_id = b7.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b7.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle8_ b8 ON pe.enc_id = b8.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b8.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle9_ b9 ON pe.enc_id = b9.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b9.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle10_ b10 ON pe.enc_id = b10.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b10.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle11_ b11 ON pe.enc_id = b11.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b11.eso1, '') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT      pe.enc_id AS enc_id
FROM        patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN  Bottle12_ b12 ON pe.enc_id = b12.enc_id
AND         pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
AND         ISNULL(b12.eso1, '') <> ''
),
totals AS(
SELECT              pm.description AS [Physician],
                    e.event AS [Procedure],
                    COUNT(j.enc_id) AS [Total Jars],
                    COUNT(pe.enc_id) AS [Total Encounters],
                    CASE WHEN COUNT(pe.enc_id) <> 0 THEN CONVERT(float, COUNT(j.enc_id))/CONVERT(float, COUNT(pe.enc_id)) ELSE 0 END AS [AvgTotal]
FROM                patient_encounter pe
INNER JOIN          person p ON pe.person_id = p.person_id AND pe.practice_id = @practice_id
INNER JOIN          appointments ap ON pe.enc_id = ap.enc_id
                                    AND ap.resched_ind = 'N'
                                    AND ap.delete_ind = 'N'
                                    AND ap.cancel_ind = 'N'
                                    AND ap.appt_kept_ind = 'Y'
INNER JOIN          events e ON ap.event_id = e.event_id
INNER JOIN          provider_mstr pm ON pe.rendering_provider_id = pm.provider_id
INNER JOIN          location_mstr lm ON pe.location_id = lm.location_id
LEFT JOIN           (SELECT enc_id
                     FROM jars
                     GROUP BY enc_id) AS j ON pe.enc_id = j.enc_id
WHERE               pe.enc_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
GROUP pm.description, e.event)
SELECT [Physician], [Procedure], 
       Avg([Total Jars]) [Total Jars], 
       Avg([Total Encounters]) [Total Encounters], 
       Avg([AvgTotal]) [AvgTotal]
from totals
GROUP BY [Physician], [Procedure]
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: This is definitely progress, but it's still not quite right and I probably didn't explain it correctly. If you look at the output in my original post, I would like to insert the average in between [Total Jars] and [Total Encounters]. In that example, I would expect to see the average for Procedure A being derived from [Total Jars] divided by the number of [Total Encounters].

Also, this loses the grand totals, but it's late here and I'm likely not seeing this clearly now. :-)

Comment: Also, in an effort to clarify, this simply adds the [Total Jars] for each procedure and divides by 3. It should really be looking for averages at each procedure and getting the average by using the [Total Encounters] column.

Comment: it is possible. Can you show the formula using the real column names

Comment: So, the real column names don't exist in the table. We have to basically COUNT the number of jars (COUNT(j.enc_id) = [Total Jars]) and the number of encounters (procedures) by doing a COUNT of the total number of encounters during that period of time (COUNT(pe.enc_id) = [Total Encounters]). I tried to modify the last SELECT statement of your query to include something like ([Total Jars] / [Total Encounters]) AS [Average Jars]), but I get an error message: Column 'totals.Total Jars' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: And then adding [Total Jars] and [Total Encounters] into the GROUP BY clause messes up the output. I appreciate your help and hanging in there on this one with me. Any additional insight you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, check the updated answer. I have added an `AvgTotal` column.

Comment: Ah, so forgetting to convert the numbers to floats was really my problem the whole time. When I had previously tried to calculate the average, I was always getting back zeros, so I thought I was doing something incorrectly. Well, I guess technically, I was, since I wasn't accounting for the right data type. Thank you so much for your expertise and timely assistance with this problem. I really appreciate it. I'd vote up your answer, but apparently I need to build up my reputation before I can. Answer marked as answered, though. Thank you once again!